# How would the airline carrier compensate if the change in flight schedule breaks my entire itinerary?

Tags: regulations, compensation, itineraries, passenger-rights

I planned a trip to Europe this December and booked the flights quite in advance. A few days ago they sent an email informing me that a flight has been cancelled and they offered a different flight or refund of the booking amount. However there are several other booked flights (with different carriers) and hotel bookings which would suffer because of this change.

Here's my itinerary:-

1. Delhi (DEL) to Milan (MXP), Air Italy, dep. Sunday, 6am India time
2. Milan (MXP) to Rome (FCO), Air Italy, dep. Sunday 12.45pm Italy time
3. Rome (CIA) to Athens (ATH), Ryanair, dep. Monday, 10am Italy time

Return:

1. Athens (ATH) to Rome(CIA), Ryanair, Thursday
2. Rome (FCO) to Milan (MXP), Air Italy, dep Friday, 9.40am Italy time
3. Milan (MXP) to Delhi (DEL), Air Italy, dep Friday, 4pm Italy time
4. Delhi (DEL) to Hyderabad (HYD), Indigo, dep Sunday

Of course the onward and return journey is separated by a few weeks. Not mentioning the dates due to privacy reasons.

They informed about two cancellations:
Delhi to Milan (onward - Sunday)
and 
Milan to Delhi (return Friday)

However they offer these flights on different days which totally break my itinerary which might cause me missing the connections of good amount of money to get other flights rescheduled.

I tried to communicate with them but

- Sent messages on whatsapp but I'm not receiving response after one reply
- Sent a couple of email on separate days but didn't get a reply
- Couldn't get connected on Phone.

It is causing a lot of stress.

What can I do about it?

I'd like to know what are my rights regarding how airlines is bound to (1) attend to customer communications, (2) offer multiple alternatives which do not break the itinerary, and (3) offer additional compensation for additional costs involved (hotels, other flights re-schdeuled).

Comment: Air Italy have no responsibility for the flights you have booked with other carriers. Do you have travel insurance?

Comment: @Traveller Oh that's weird. But do you see I had sufficient time margin between all the flights just to avoid such a situation.

Comment: @Aditya Certainly you had enough time for a small change, but not enough for a large one or a cancellation. I'm afraid the answer posed by jpatokal is indeed correct. All I can suggest is to ask Air Italy if flights some days *earlier* might be substituted. If so, while you might have to secure additional interim lodging, you could use the other bookings you've made.

Comment: Did you book the entire sequence of flights on a single ticket, or did you go around to different airlines and purchase tickets independently of one another?

Comment: @Harper Ryanair does not interline with anybody (except Air Europa), so the tickets will be separate.

Comment: Talk to your travel insurance company.  You do have travel insurance, right?

Comment: WhatsApp? Who are you talking too on WhatsApp?

Comment: @Doc why do you assume OP has travel insurance? What is it about the OP's itinerary(ies) that makes travel insruance an obvious choice?

Comment: I do have travel insurance @stannius but Idk if it would help in this case. Anyways I was able to get connect to Air Italy through their area agent in my country - lets see how much time they take to fix it.

Comment: You could do Rome <-> Milan by train in a pinch, it would take a bit longer (3-4 hours) so it depends on if the schedule is more convenient.

Comment: @stannius The OP is travelling internationally.  That makes travel insurance an obvious choice!

Comment: @Doc The concept of "travel insurance" as a wholistic type of insurance may be uncommon in the OPs place of residence. As a non-Indian example, the German wikipedia page for "travel insurance" states that the term is used for all types of travel-related insurances, include travel cancellation insurance, travel health insurace, travel accident insurance, travel baggage insurance, ...; and they are offered individually or in combination (I can tell you that the latter is rare). Insurances that also cover connections may be very hard to come by if they are uncommon in the OPs place of residence.

Comment: it is utterly inconceivable "travel insurance" would help in any way in this specific exact case, unfortunately

Comment: I suppose the DEL-MXP and MXP-FCO (and return) flights are booked on the same ticket, right? Where do you actually need/want to be? It looks like one night in Rome both ways, is that something you need, or just as a buffer between Air Italy and Ryanair on your way to/from Athens?

Comment: @Doc Don’t think my insurance covers me for consequential losses following an air carrier rescheduling a flight. Would be interested to hear who does cover it. Suspect it would be cheaper to self-insure that possibility.

Answer (score 57):

I'm afraid that, because you booked your Air Italy and Ryanair flights separately, **your connections are not the airline's concern**.

Air Italy is obliged to offer you a choice between alternative transport to your destination (which does not have to be on the same days etc) or a full refund.  That's it.  You can try to negotiate for better flights than the ones they're offering you, maybe even an alternative connection straight to Athens, but at the end of the day you can't force them.   You are *not* entitled to any compensation.

Comment: May be worth re-iterating that one should book *all* flights via the same airline to avoid this situation. I'm still surprised this is not more widely known.

Comment: Realistically that's often just not possible. For one thing, not all airlines fly all routes or go to the desired locations, and "choose different destinations is unhelpful advice. For another thing, most people are working and get very limited numbers of days for vacations and personal travel, so "allow a day between flights" or similar advice may also be impractical in real-world scenarios. I'm not sure if there is a solution, but the above comment feels like it should be a "try to do this if practical" rather than "you _should_ always do this".

Comment: @Stilez In all my years of travelling I never had a problem getting from A to B on a single ticket. Just because you *book* on one airline doesn't mean you'll actually fly with it, just with one of their partner airlines (and all major airlines are parts of large networks these days). Delhi-Rome is anything but impossible to get on one ticket. It might be a bit more expensive than buying separate tickets, but this here is a good example of the trouble you might get in. So no the advice is pretty universally valid.

Comment: @Voo I agree that's it's valid advice, but it's still not always practical. Consider for example Poznań to Paris, where the only direct flight is with Wizz Air, a small Hungarian outfit that is not part of any major network. Flying with another airline (to remain on the same ticket) takes more money and more time and may not be practical.

Comment: @rturnbull yes, sometimes it's impossible to book everything on a single ticket. Like when I was in Indonesia we had to fly with a small local operation because Garuda didn't offer flights to where we were going. We did calculate in delays and took a 24 hour overlay just in case in Denpassar because of that. Turned out we didn't need it, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: @rturnbull The thing is, if you need to get from Poznan to Paris, then that flight is sufficient. If you need to get from Poznan to another place, you can probably get there through more paths than only Paris and thus could probably find a different carrier and itinerary.

Comment: @jwenting , what you say is true in adventure travel.   It really does not apply here  and will only confuse the OP.

Comment: @Stilez your comment is basically totally incorrect, because Delhi - Athens is a huge, major route.  The OP "must" follow the absolutely basic rule of air travel, which is "book one ticket".  That's the only way to make airlines responsible.  Anything else will pointlessly confuse OP.

Comment: Everything @voo says is of course correct.  Just BTW voo as you suspect Delhi-Athens is a huge route, and it is trivial to get cheap fares all at once on 7? major airlines.  (I bet that in fact the bizarre "air italy" (wth?) and the other unmentionable "airline" combo was a much worse price.  My guess is OP was thrown off by OP's need for the shuttle Delhi-Hyd. at the end ..   :O )

Comment: @Matthieu M. as other users mentioned, it was not possible to have a single airline or single ticket for my journey. It would have become too expensive.

Comment: On comments by @Voo yes it was expansive to buy by almost 1.5 times. JetAirways and KLM have a tie-up and they would have given a single ticket till Rome but the total was coming more than my one month's salary plus additional 14-16 hours in layovers etc. Plus it's not just Rome. The flight is like DEL > MILAN > ROME > ATHENS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84188/discussion-between-aditya-and-fattie).

Comment: @Fattie it's no different. We weren't going to some bush strip in Papua, we were going to a rather large city on another island, a city that happened to only be covered by other airlines than Garuda. No different from flying in Europe and needing to have a leg in there not covered by one of the majors.

Comment: For folks who have never been to asia, travelling DELHI TO ATHENS is very much like traveling NEW YORK TO LOS ANGELES.  Except that the populations involved are 5x? bigger than a comic small country like the US.  Consider the idea of booking a bizarre combo flight on comic airlines with separate tickets for NEW YORK TO LOS ANGELES , and you get an idea how absurd is doing so for Delhi - Athens !!  Geesh!  I mean this is a PRIMARY ROUTE for emirates (!!!!) turkish (!!!!) qatar (!!!!) etc etc.  It would be like not noticing that you can fly, say, oh, "Delta" from NY to LA  :)  :)

Comment: @Fattie No, DEL-ATH is *nothing at all* like NYC-LAX.  Athens (both city & airport) is much smaller than either US city, and there are no non-stop flights between the two.

Comment: I don't know what more can be said on this question.  There are many comments like "Oh my God!!!!!!! Sometimes you DO NEED to book separate flights!" is so completely absurd between Delhi-Athens, that I just don't know what can be said.  I mean, Dubai .. DUBAI !!!!!! .. is in the middle.  If you're never been to Asia, it would be like not understanding you can trivially fly between two places connecting to Atlanta.  There is a massive, overwhelming amount of India <-> European Capitals traffic.

Comment: @Voo Going from KUO to IST is already a problem - the KUO-HEL leg is exclusively Finnair, and HEL-IST is exclusively TK (w/ SK codeshare). They are not partners and can't sell each other's tickets. The only way to make this journey is to buy separate tickets and hope the KUO-HEL leg doesn't go wrong.

I believe that you have never been to such rural destinations where they are only served by a domestic flight with a small carrier.

Answer (score 4):

Your only option is to pick an earlier flight so your itinerary is not messed up.

In Europe we have usually a very good compensation system for denied boarding and cancelled flights. You can check up on the rules if you search for passenger rights.

SADLY, it does **not apply to you**, since you have booked each flight on their own and also the airline informed you well ahead of time (> 14 days)

The General rules for refunds in Europe are as follows (Any flight leaving Europe and any **European Airline** flying to Europe):

Cancelation < 14 days of flight / denied boarding (even with alternate flights, but refunds may be reduced if you get there in time)  / Flight Delayed >3 H :

- full refund AND compensation based on distance traveled between 250 and 650 € (Cash, not vouchers)
- Hotel in case of needed overnight
- food/phone calls in case of delay >3h

Claiming these benefits you need to contact the executing airline. I suggest you do not use any 3rd party website in order to claim, since they take a cut of the refunds and its only 2 emails or so to get the compensation.

Unforseen events may void this. Plane breakdowns are not unforseens/unexpected since they happen all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you paid 'Air Italy' just once, the good news is that your contract with 'Air Italy' is to get you from Delhi to Rome and back again.  If they cancelled the DEL-MXP legs, they should be offering you an alternative.  They have NO responsibility for the Ryanair flights or the Indigo flight to Hyderabad, assuming you paid separately for these.  If 'Air Italy' can reschedule you to arrive in Rome before the Ryanair flight to Athens (and also reschedule your departure from Rome after your Ryanair flight arrives), you might be able to keep the other flights.

To echo some of the other replies and comments: Why would you want to fly such a complex routing, when many airlines seem to offer Delhi to Athens with just a single stop?  A complex routing like this is big a chance for something to go wrong: delays, cancellations, lost luggage, endless hanging around in foreign airports, and perhaps the need for a transit visa as well.  An added complication is that once in Rome, you would need to collect your luggage, transfer to another airport and check in your luggage again.  Also, if you are a non-EU passport holder, flying Ryanair has the added difficulty of needing to visit their special desk so your visa can be 'validated' before they will let you board.